# Cant load an image in Django Application

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, backend

I'm trying to build an app and I want from **views.py** to save an image in a specific file and after that call the image from the **template** using **static**

I try this

```
path_to_save = r"..\AISystem\texttohandwriting\static\result.png"
        BG.save(
            rf"{path_to_save}")

    return render(request, "text_to_handwriting.html", context)
```

as you can see I saved the image that was produced in the **static\result.png** and it saves correctly since i see the image. < The image **changes** every time the user enters a text

in the **HTML** file, I do this

```
<img width="400" height="400"  src="{%static 'result.png' %}" alt="">
```

Terminal show this

`Could not find file. Using default file...`

`[29/Aug/2023 17:39:00] "POST /text_to_handwriting.html HTTP/1.1" 200 992`

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's clarify: Static files are not meant to be changed during the runtime of your app. That's literally where the name 'static' comes from. Especially when you use your app in production this gets messy because then the command `python manage.py collectstatic` is required to pull all the static files.

Every file that is changed during runtime of your app, or e.g. affected by user input has to go to the media folder.

Still this is not the best approach because this will clutter the drive of your server. You would have to have a process that deletes the files every now and then, right? Or do you want to store them persistently?

I would recommend displaying the results 'on the fly' to the user, meaning saving the figure to a buffer. Find a good example [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/web_application_server_sgskip.html). This is for matplotlib and flask, but the procedure is the same.

```py
    # ...
    buf = BytesIO()
    BG.save(buf, format="png")
    # Embed the result in the html output.
    data = base64.b64encode(buf.getbuffer()).decode("ascii")
    context['my_image'] = f"<img src='data:image/png;base64,{data}'/>"

    return render(request, "text_to_handwriting.html", context)
```

your_template.html

```html
{% autoescape off %}
{{ my_image }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

To make this approach work it is necessary that your `BG.save` can save to a buffer. But normally that works.